# dual boot windows 8.1 and debian 8.2

Tags: debian, windows, dual-boot

Can anyone suggest among the following options which one would be the best option to install **Debian 8.2.0** alongside on a system with (**Windows 8.1** - booting mode **UEFI on GPT disk**) installed :

```
(1) UEFI with Secure Boot Enabled 
                   or
(2) UEFI with Secure Boot Disabled
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debian 8.2 should support UEFI just fine, provided you use one of the [official installation images](https://www.debian.org/CD/). Secure boot is not currently supported, however, so you should switch that off.

Comment: I have the Secure Boot currently enabled. So won't it affect or become problematic with Windows 8.1 startup/booting?

Comment: [No](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824987.aspx).

Comment: What if I install Debian alongside with Secure Boot enabled, since it is enabled by default in my system?

Comment: Debian doesn't support Secure Boot, so your system won't even boot the installer *unless* you switch off Secure Boot in the firmware *first*.

Comment: But this is not the case with ubuntu latest stable release.

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu does support secure boot. Ubuntu is not Debian, however, and Debian does not support secure boot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34787/discussion-between-deep-chandra-and-wouter-verhelst).